# Remove the space above/below itemizes and descriptions

Tags: spacing, lists, context, itemize, description

In the document below an itemize is nested in a description and I want to have no vertical space between the entries.

I removed the space above and below of itemizes and descriptions using `\vskip-\parskip`, but this might not be the right way. And it does not work if the itemize is the first content inside a description.

I tried to use the `joinedup` and `nowhite` as shown [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Enumerations#Vertical_spacing), but then the spacing still exists.

**How to remove the space above/below itemizes and descriptions?**

**Code:**

```
\definedescription[description][
    alternative=left,
    width=2em,
    before={\vskip-\parskip},  %<<< ?
    after={\vskip-\parskip},   %<<< ?
]

\setupitemize[each][packed][   % [joinedup,nowhite] don't change spacing
    before={\vskip-\parskip},  %<<< ?
    after={\vskip-\parskip},   %<<< ?
]

\starttext

    \startdescription{Foo}
        \input knuth
    \stopdescription

    \startdescription{Bar}
        \startitemize
        \item ↑ Too much space above ↑
        \item Just some Text
        \item Just some Text
        \stopitemize
    \stopdescription

    \startdescription{Baz}
        A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. 
        \startitemize
        \item Just some Text
        \item Just some Text
        \item Just some Text
        \stopitemize
        A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. 
    \stopdescription

\stoptext
```

**Result:**

[image: output document]

Used ConTeXt version is `2013.05.28 00:36`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConTeXt does remove such spaces when you use nested itemize, for example

```
\startitemize
  \item 
    \startitemize
      \item One
      \item Two
    \stopitemize
\stopitemize
```

but there is no high level interface for this. However, it is easy to provide a wrapper around the low level commands

```
\unprotect
\define\concatitemgroup{\hskip\d_strc_itemgroups_signal}
\protect
```

and then use

```
\startdescription{Bar}
  \concatitemgroup
  \startitemize
    \item ↑ Too much space above ↑
    \item Just some Text
    \item Just some Text
  \stopitemize
\stopdescription
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use

```
\startitemize[before=\concatitemgroup]
```

because the `before` is triggered too late in `\startitemize`. For automatically workflow, you can define your own description rendering setup.

```
\unprotect
\startsetups[\??constructionrenderings:leftconcat]
    \directsetup{\??constructionrenderings:\v!left:\v!none}
    \hskip\d_strc_itemgroups_signal
\stopsetups

\defineconstructionalternative
  [leftconcat]
  [\c!renderingsetup=\??constructionrenderings:leftconcat]

\def\concatitemgroup{\hskip\d_strc_itemgroups_signal}

\protect

\definedescription
  [description]
  [
    alternative=leftconcat,
    width=2em,
  ]

\setupitemize[packed]

\starttext
    \startdescription{Bar}
      \startitemize
        \item ↑ Too much space above ↑
        \item Just some Text
        \item Just some Text
      \stopitemize
    \stopdescription

    \startdescription{Baz}
        A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. 
        \startitemize
        \item Just some Text
        \item Just some Text
        \item Just some Text
        \stopitemize
        A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. A line that contains some text. 
    \stopdescription
  \stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

For no vertical space, simply add

```
\setupitemize[nowhite]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Is it advisable to use `\vskip-\parskip` in `\definedescription` to remove space between description entries or is there some more "official way"?