# ConTeXt: How to remove vertical space before top section headings in columns?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, context, columns

It has gotten that far that I have made a shopping list with ConTeXt…

However, there remains one æsthetic problem:
**There is some unwanted vertical space above those section headings which are located at the very top of any column.**
[image: vertical space above column section headings]

The section headings are defined as follows:

```
\setuphead[section][
  style={\bfb\setupinterlinespace},
  before={\testcolumn[4]},
  after={\vskip-\parskip}
  ]
```

Here is the complete source of my shopping list.

```
\mainlanguage[nl]


% Pages
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuplayout[
  height=middle,
  topspace=0cm,
  bottomspace=1cm,
  width=middle,
  backspace=2.5cm,
  cutspace=2.5cm
]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,center}]


% Fonts
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default] [em=italic]

%% https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfallback
%% The rscale=auto option ensures that all fonts have the same x-height.
\definefallbackfamily [fontfamilies] [serif] [FreeSerif] [range=0x00000-0xFFFFF, force=no, rscale=auto]
\definefontfamily     [fontfamilies] [serif] [TeX Gyre Pagella]
\setupbodyfont        [fontfamilies,11.5pt]


% Sections
\setuphead[section, subsection, subsubsection][number=no]

\setuphead[section][
  style={\bfb\setupinterlinespace},
  % TODO Remove the vertical space before any top section head of each column.
  before={\testcolumn[4]}, % The absolute minimum!
  after={\vskip-\parskip}
  ]


% Inter-paragraph spacing
\setupwhitespace[small]

\setupitemize[
    % Remove space before and after item lists.
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130561/26348
      before={\vskip-\parskip},
      after={\vskip-\parskip},
    % Item text starts at a larger distance to allow for wider item symbols.
      distance=1em
]

% Change the first level item symbol.
\definesymbol[1][☐ ☐]

% Break at hyphens
\setbreakpoints[compound]

% Lists
\setupitemize[autointro]    % prevent orphan list intro
\setupitemize[indentnext=no]


\starttext
\startcolumns[n=3]

\section[brood]{Brood}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  brood
\item
  honing
\stopitemize

\section[fruit]{Fruit}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  sinaasappelen
\item
  citroenen
\item
  appelen
\item
  peren
\item
  kiwi's
\item
  meloenen
\item
  paprika's
\item
  bananen
\item
  noten
\stopitemize

\section[groenten]{Groenten}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  aardappelen
\item
  uien
\item
  radijzen
\item
  rode bieten
\item
  tomaten
\item
  komkommers
\stopitemize

\section[vloeistoffen]{Vloeistoffen}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  azijn
\item
  frituurolie
\item
  mayonaise
\item
  spaghettisaus
\stopitemize

\section[droogwaren]{Droogwaren}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  bouillonblokjes
\item
  rijst
\item
  pasta
\item
  tonijn
\item
  champignons
\item
  erwten
\item
  asperges
\item
  uitjes
\item
  gedroogde bieslook
\item
  müsli
\item
  chocolade
\stopitemize

\section[koelwaren]{Koelwaren}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  taart
\item
  pannenkoeken
\item
  rucola
\item
  veldsla
\item
  gazpacho
\item
  lasagne
\item
  macaroni
\item
  verse pizza
\item
  tonijnsalade
\item
  ham
\stopitemize

\section[diepvrieswaren]{Diepvrieswaren}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  paella
\item
  vis
\item
  scampi's
\item
  calamares
\stopitemize

\section[zuivel]{Zuivel}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  boter
\item
  kaas
\item
  Grana Padano
\item
  yoghurt
\item
  flan
\item
  melk
\item
  eieren
\stopitemize

\section[drank]{Drank}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  tonic
\item
  koude thee
\stopitemize

\section[schoonmaak]{Schoonmaak}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  vaatwasmiddel
\item
  waspoeder kleuren
\item
  wasverzachter
\item
  bleekwater
\item
  bleekwatergel
\stopitemize

\section[hygiëne]{Hygiëne}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  vochtige doekjes
\item
  kosmetische doekjes
\item
  haarshampoo
\item
  zakdoeken
\item
  deodorant
\stopitemize

\section[aldi]{Aldi}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  koffie
\item
  brood
\item
  water
\item
  vis
\item
  olijfolie
\item
  augurken
\item
  frieten
\item
  paella
\item
  kroketten
\stopitemize

\section[action]{Action}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  bakpapier
\item
  handzeep
\item
  douchezeep
\item
  vitamines
\stopitemize

\section[kruidvat]{Kruidvat}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  tandpasta
\item
  tandenborstels Signal
\item
  tandenstokers
\item
  oorstaafjes
\item
  eau de cologne
\stopitemize

\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

Comment: This seems to come from the column balancing algorithm.  You should ask about this on the mailing list.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but can you use `joinedup` for `\setupitemize` instead of `\vskip-\parskip`? See the [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupitemgroup#Description) for details.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Sorry Dave, nice suggestion, but `joinedup` is not resolving this issue.

Comment: The mailing list is probably your best bet, @SergeStroobandt.